# Am I doing it right with this CLI command line?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Hi I am trying to use CLI to access my safe. The problem is when I am trying to execute the command to send an erc-20 token, as you can see below, so I put the wallet address first and the token contract address after that. But the problem is that it says it is sending the token to the contract address, is that right? Am I doing something wrong?

send_erc20 0x1dE---ab4Bc 0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B8
8837ca1490cCa17c31607 1
Result: True
Do you want to execute tx SafeTx - safe=0xffb17---0F6d6 - to=0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B88837ca1490cCa17c31607

(I have intentionally omitted parts of the wallet address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the ERC-20 tokens to the token contract address, I dont think that is what you want to do, call the `transfer` function on the token.

An example command for sending ERC-20 token would be that `send_erc20 <token_contract_address> <recipient_address> <amount>`

so your command should be

```
send_erc20 0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B8 0x1dE---ab4Bc 8837ca1490cCa17c31607 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I confirm the transaction but it seems there is a problem with the gas allowance. Do you know how I can fix that as well? Here's part of the error as I cannot fit all of it in a comment:
...
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (550000000)'}

Comment: the gas required for the transaction exceeds the allowance set, increase the gas allowance

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not sure how I can increase it and what amount should it be. Can you give me a sample command line, please? Something that I use alongside the transfer command.